# Does the person get notified when their calendar is being added by others?

Tags: google-workspace, google-calendar, google-apps-for-work, google-workspace-for-business

In GSuite's Calendar, you are able to add calendar of other members (co-workers) within the same organization.

Let's say when I add John's Calendar to my **Other calendars**, will John get notified that his calendar was added by someone?

If so, what kind of details are revealed to John if any?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally tested with multiple accounts on GSuite.

There were no notification upon calendar being added by other members within the organization.

So no, John will not be notified.